# Error handling and minimize script output to end-user

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a script which loops through a list of users (samaccountname):

```
# Read usersfile to variable
$users = get-content ("users.txt")

# Get current time
$now = $(get-date -uformat "%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")

# Loop through list of users
foreach($user in $users) {

    # Disable user
    Disable-QADUser $user

    # Set informative description
    Set-QADuser $user -Description "Disabled $now"

    # Delete all groupmemberships except "domain users"
    Get-QADGroup -Containsmember $user | where-object { $_.name -ne 'domain users'} | Remove-QADGroupmember

    # Move to "disabled users" group
    move-QADObject $user -NewParentContainer 'contosoc.com/Disabled users'

    # Hide from addresslist
    Set-Mailbox -identity $user -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true

    # Moving mailbox to disabled users database
    Move-Mailbox -Identity $user -TargetDatabase "myserver\mydb" -BadItemLimit 50 -Confirm:$False
}
```

I would like to:

- Suppress output from the different cmdlets and only show "$user is OK!" if all is ok and log success to a logfile.txt
- Display "Error!" and the command that failed if not ok. And output the complete error msgs to a separate logfile.

I've been thinking about doing a `if(!cmdlettorun) { write-host "Error!" }` But I'm thinking that there must be a better way.

How should I do error handling in a proper fashion so I minimize the displayed output but still let me see it if desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For suppressing cmlet output you can pipe to `out-null` or precede the command with:

```
[void](.. your cmdlets..)
```

a good way for your goal is using a tray-catch-finally code like in this minimized code:

```
$a = $ErrorActionPreference 
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

foreach($user in $users) {

try 
{
... yours code ...
$JobStatus = "OK"
}
catch [exception]
{
   $("Error catched: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName) | out-file c:\file.log
   $("Error catched: " + $_.Exception.Message) | out-file c:\file.log -append

   $JobStatus = "not OK"
   continue; 
}
finally
{
   write-host "$user is $JobStatus!"
}
  $ErrorActionPreference = $a
}
```

For some hint to use `try-catch-finally` read [here](http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/)

Comment: Finally will always execute so `"$user is OK!"` will always print... even if there was an exception!

Comment: Thank you Christian. But how would I output the error msg to a file? I get "empty pipeline not allowed" if i try to pipe it via out-file.

Comment: @sune: look answer, I edited to modify $ErrorActionPreference and reset the old value at the end of script.

Comment: Thank you Christian! I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.. How do I do a `write-host "All is ok"` if NO errors have occured?

Comment: @Sune add a `$error.clear()` at the start of the script. At the end test $error like this `if(!$error) {write-host "All is ok"}`